# EditText изменение данных в модели и применение измененных данных MVP

Tags: java, android, mvp, moxy

Моя реализация очень похожа на тот что в [примере](https://medium.com/cr8resume/make-you-hand-dirty-with-mvp-model-view-presenter-eab5b5c16e42)

Только я использую Moxy с его ViewStates.
И при изменении текста в EditText я сообщаю об этом презентеру, презентер кладет измененные данные в модель и говорит VIEW чтобы тот засетил данное значение. Но в отличии от примера, когда презентер говорит "засетать" значение, активити сетает данное значение обратно в EditText откуда первоначально значение были отправлено в презентер. Получается цикличность, это я решаю так `.distinctUntilChanged()`:

```
    RxTextView.textChanges(titleView)
            .skip(1)
            .map(CharSequence::toString)
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .subscribe(presenter::changingTitle);
```

Теперь, при вводе с клавиатуры, когда презентер говорит "засеть" данные, происходит `titleView.setText(textFromPresenter)`при каждом вводе символа, и курсор переходит в начало EditText'а (и еще невозможно удалять значения удерживая кнопку Delete на клавиатуре, тоже сразу переходит курсор на начало). Решил это так:  `debounce(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` - чтобы можно было удалять непрерывно и `titleView.setSelection(textFromPresenter.length())` - чтобы курсор всегда был в конце ввода

```
RxTextView.textChanges(titleView)
            .skip(1)
            .debounce(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .observeOn(rx.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .map(CharSequence::toString)
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .subscribe(presenter::changingTitle);

@Override
public void setTitle(@Nullable String textFromPresenter) {
    this.titleView.setText(textFromPresenter);
    if (textFromPresenter != null) this.titleView.setSelection(textFromPresenter.length());
}
```

Мой экран, это аля AddOrUpdateView, при открытии этого экрана модель может быть уже заполнено(режим редактирования), при этом призентер при первом аттаче сетает данные из модели и сохранеят эти действия в [ViewStates](https://github.com/Arello-Mobile/Moxy/wiki/View-commands-state-strategy). Если перевернуть экран, данные будут восстановлены из ViewState, и из-за этого необходимо при изменении в модели сетать данные через презентер (AddToEndSingleStrategy, чтобы обновить ViewState).

> Да, наверное, можно было бы убрать некоторые State из ViewState и не
>   парится, но если каждый раз пренебрегать принципами MVP то зачем вообще 
>   использовать его..? p.s. Все конечно по своему понимают эти принципы, может и я 
>   неправильно понял и занимаюсь Over-Engineering. Может и не нужно делать как я ) 
>   Направьте на путь истинный

Как бы вы вышли с этой ситуации? **Только не нарушая каноны MVP!**

Comment: Опишите свою задачу. Пока что можно лишь предположить, что раз вы данные из поля ввода берёте, то вам и не нужно обратно их же сетить. Т.е., наверное, можно отдельный метод в презентере сделать, который будет обновлять модель, но не трогать вью.

Comment: Все таки, хотелось, чтобы  вью отображало то что приходит с презентера. т.к. в презентере есть viewState, и при первом attach он сетает данные и если после изменения не просетать еще раз новые данные через презентор то при смене конфигураций на экране будут старые данные. Сейчас обновлю вопрос, будет понятнее о чем я.

Comment: Если я правильно понял у вас как-то так должно быть: 1. Входим на фрагмент и сетим данные из презентера в поле ввода. 2. Меняем что-то в поле ввода, обновляя модель в презентере. 3. Поворачиваем экран и в модели в презентере должны быть изменённые данные как и в поле ввода во вью. Это верно? Если да, то у меня всё это работает и без необходимости сетить данные из перзентера во вью при изменениях в поле ввода, т.к. EditText автоматически самостоятельно восстанавливает состояние. Чтобы оно не перезаписывалось изначальными данными, то вам надо просто использовать стратегию нужную.

Comment: Вроде как вам нужна тут `OneExecutionStateStrategy`

Comment: Да, я с вами полностью согласен. Но я хотел абстрагироваться от компонента android, EditText'а.  И учесть то что может будет элемент, который не умеет сохранять свой state.  Хотя, со стороны, согласен, нахрена это...)

Comment: Если бы состояние не восстанавливалось автоматически, то можно было бы так сделать: 1. Перенести установку изначального значения из `onFirstViewAttach` в `public void attachView(View view)`. Так при каждом присоединении View данные бы туда сетились. 2. Данные сетить надо в этом случае после вызова `super(view)` у метода `public void attachView(View view)`. 3. Также убрать установку значения во View при каждом изменении в поле ввода. 4. Также использовать стратегию `OneExecutionStateStrategy `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то наиболее правильный вариант делать проверку в presenter.
В presenter можно хранить текущее состояние title, и если новое значение которое прилетает в changingTitle не отличается от  текущего title, то мы просто игнорируем и не меняем state

Comment: Ага, у меня, сейчас такая схема. Но вариант выше тоже интересный. В понедельник, на работе, надо все это подумать) спасибо!